# NetBeans 8.1 Cannot connect to the remote repository

Tags: java, git, github, netbeans

I'm trying to setup github with netbeans using the https path. I go to the push menu and enter the info it needs for repo URL and username/password but when I hit next it just says "Cannot connect to the remote repository at *my repository*" I've done a little bit of research but nothing has helped so far.

I tried reinstalling netbeans but i'm getting the same error. I should also mention that it works just fine on my laptop.

It appears that netbeans has no network connectivity. It fails to check for updates as well. I tried disabling anti-virus and firewall but neither helped. My computer definitely has internet. I successfully checked updates on my laptop which was on the same network.

The main error that I keep seeing is Unexpected end of file from server whenever I check for updates or test connection in options.

Here is a link to the relevant log: [Pastebin LogFile](http://pastebin.com/xUUi0rUz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit. Apparently Covenant Eyes is blocking all network connectivity within NetBeans. After reinstalling Covenant Eyes it appears to working now. For now i'm going to mark this as solved unless something else comes up.